# Merge conflict Git

Tags: git, egit

I and my friend fork from the main repository (upstream). Last night, we had the same version of this repository in local machine. Then I have added a new feature and my friend also added another new feature too. My friend pulled request to the main repository and I have merge this pull request with the upstream repository with no conflict. And when I fetch from upstream and merge with my master branch, it conflicts.
What should I do in this situation to resolve conflict? (The upstream repository should have 2 new features after resolving conflict)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just go through the files marked as conflicted by `git status` and find the conflict markers (you can search for `====` in the file). Reconcile the changes between them, figure out if anything else unexpected got broken by the combination of your code, run your tests, and then use `git add` and `git commit` as normal to make a commit merging your friend's new feature with yours.

```
Upstream: original                 with friend's feature            with both
               \  \               /                \               /
                \  -- Friend's --/                  \             /
                 \                                   \           /
                  ---- Yours ------------------------- your merge
```

Answer (score 10):

Note that you can also solve directly a merge conflict from Eclipse/Egit itself:
See "[Egit: Solving Merge Conflicts](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html#team_mergeconflicts)":

> You can manually edit the text on the left side or use the Copy current change from right to left button to copy the conflicting changes from right to left.
>
> Next step is from the context menu of the file, to select Team -> Add to index. Than commit.

[image: merge conflict resolution in EGit]

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674950/how-to-do-an-ours-merge-using-the-eclipse-git-merge-tool as an example of that tool usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can type `git difftool path/filename` in the console to use a tool to resolve the conflict or use Git software that has conflict resolution built in. I really like SmartGit (from the makers of SmartSVN) and TortoiseGit (very similar to TortoiseSVN).