# Remove history of a file from just a single branch, not the entire repo

Tags: git

I have a topic branch (off `master`) has that lots of changes. Throughout the history of this topic branch there's been numerous changes to a certain file. How can remove all changes to this file throughout the history of my topic branch?

Additional notes:

- Note that the file existed ***before*** the topic branch was created. I don't want to delete the file per se.
- I have a couple of solutions, but so far they seem tedious. I'll post them as separate answers.
- Can `git filter-branch` somehow be used for this?
- My topic branch contains around...say...60 commits.

Comment: Do you want to remove the changes from history, or is it ok, if the changes are dropped when merging to master?

Comment: `git filter-branch` can definitely do it.  What you want is: for each new commit, if that file was modified, un-modify it by re-loading the desired version.  If the file was not modified, you can still read the desired version, since that will be a no-op.  I think this can be done with `--index-filter` and `git update-index`.  (I'd have to experiment to make it work, myself.)  Edit: or, yes, `git checkout <rev> -- <path>`, as in your own answer :-)

Comment: knittl: I want the changes removed from history.

Comment: On a side note, 60 commits is a lot for a feature branch. From a dev process standpoint, the scope of your features may be too large. Either that, or you should consider squashing your commits in the feature branch more.

Comment: Cupcake: Indeed. This was the result of a summer intern that we failed to communicate early merging to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `git filter-branch`:

```
$ git checkout topic-branch
$ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git checkout master -- myfile' master..HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

Rebase the tree against the start of the branch. Use attributes to determine a different merge strategy for that particular file, in particular 'merge.ours' (always keep our file). This thread explains how to: [tell git to use ours merge strategy on specific files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093540/tell-git-to-use-ours-merge-strategy-on-specific-files) (the question itself tells you how to do it, the answer is simply a gotcha that the questioner had).

I don't know how 'tedious' this is, eg whether you have to confirm something at each commit, because I haven't done it. But I would think not.

Comment: I believe you it would work, but it sounds a bit complicated!

Answer (score 0):

Do an interactive rebase. The tedious version would be to simply edit/modify every commit removing the change:

```bash
git checkout topic-branch
git rebase -i master    
# set all commits to edit

# for every commit; do
git show --stat
# if myfile is not changes: git rebase --continue

# copy the commit message
git reset HEAD^
git reset myfile
git checkout myfile
git commit
# paste in commit message

git rebase --continue
# ...until we are done
```

The slightly improved version is to use `git log master.. myfile` and only edit the commits listed.