# Git merge in dev configuration without adding to history (committing) or staging files

Tags: git, merge, development-environment

Suppose that I have the follwoing folder structure:

```
My Project
    | - <project files>
    | - <project configuration files>
```

Every developer has different project configurations and wants to store these files on a separate branch.

It is then possible add these configurations into the branch you are working on by doing this:

```
# Get the configurations
git checkout jakesConfigurationFileBranch -- <project configuration files>

# Don't stage these files for commit
git reset -- <project configuration files>
```

Unfortionatly this workflow isn't working great because we have configuration files scattered accross our project (our project config files, Editor preferences, etc).  IE:

```
My Project
    | - <project files with configuration files sprinkled throughout>
```

What I would really like to is merge in a branch without changing the history or staging the files.

```
git merge --files-Only jakesConfigurationFileBranch
```

---

Before running the command the tree would like like this:

```
          master
         /
*---*---*
 \
  *--* - jakesConfigurationFiles
```

And after the tree would look the same:

```
          master
         /
*---*---*
 \
  *--* - jakesConfigurationFiles
```

There is a flag called --no-commit on merge but it will perform a fast-foward merge so this doesn't always work (and won't block the pointer from being moved).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this will work:

```
git merge --no-ff --no-commit devEnv-Jake
```

Follow it up with:

```
git reset
```

to clear the files from the staging area.

---

I actually created an alias to do this:

```
alias jake-mergeDevEnv-git='git merge --no-ff --no-commit devEnv-Jake ; git reset'
```

Answer (score 0):

My general recommendation is to keep a "dev" configuration file which will work for most developers and then override that using a per developer config file which is not version controlled or use environment variables.

Comment: This works if you only have a few files and don't mind manually overwritting them or if you script the overwrite (I have done this), but I think I have found a better solution above.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that may work for you is a simple script in your post-checkout hook to construct untracked localized configs from (tracked or untracked) per-branch substitutions, [the hook's simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20087076/1290731), and on checkout for every tracked `fixmeup.@branch` file it builds file `fixmeup` by including branch-specific content.  It would be easy to modify this to do `git
show` rather than `cat` to get your merge-from-repo effect.

Another way is to use filters to fix up content, the way that works is files marked with a filter attribute run your selected command to fix up the content in arbitrary ways on checkout and add.  [VonC has a good explanation linked to further good explanations for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/1290731).