# It´s possible to have git locally branches with different config files?

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I´m wondering if It´s possible to have in my local repo a master branch with a config file using a production DB credentials, and a develop branch with a config file with different credentials and DB.

I have been searching with no luck, the closest answer I found was to use git attributes, but it only works preserving the config files in case of conflict when a merge happens. I want to keep unmodified config files on every branch all the time. does anybody know how can I achieve this?. Or any advice about how can I manage these files?

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20087076/1290731)'s one way to set up branch-specific configs.

Answer (score 1):

Git isn't really about *branches*.  It's really about *commits*.  Branches—or branch names, to be precise—are just a way to *find* commits.  It's the *commits* that matter.

If you form the question as: *Can two different commits contain files that have the same name, yet have different contents?* the answer is clear: yes, they can.

Once you ask the obvious follow-up question: *Given two different commits, in which file F has different content, when I **merge** these commits, what happens to the content of F?* you see where the problem begins to come in.

In Git, merging is about *combining work*.  Because each commit represents a *snapshot* of files, Git needs a *third* commit here.  This third commit is some shared, common commit that is on *both* branches.  Remember, in Git, a commit is often on *many branches at the same time*.  The phrase *on a branch* just means that by using the branch name—the *tip* commit of the branch—and working backwards, we get to the commit in question.

Hence, if we have a string of commits that diverges:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

we can consider *combining work* by starting with the **shared common commit** `H`, which holds a snapshot of all files.  We compare this snapshot in `H` to the snapshot in `J`.  If file *F* has changed in going from `H` to `J`, that's a change.  Next, we compare the snapshot in `H` to that in `L`.  If file *F* has changed here, that's a change.  Git will now *combine the changes*.

If the changes are "configure the system to act one way" and "configure the system to act some other way", these changes may conflict.  Whether, and how, they conflict depends on the way the configuration works.  Git only understands *lines*.  If line 47 of file *F* in commit `H` is changed in both `J` *and* `L`, and changed *differently*, that's a conflict.  If only commit `J` has a change to line 47, Git thinks it must be OK to take that change from `J`.

> I want to keep unmodified config files on every branch all the time. does anybody know how can I achieve this?

The usual answer is: *don't even try.*  These files should not be *branch*-dependent, because when you have this:

```
...--G--H   <-- master, dev
```

the files in commit `H` are the same, regardless of whether you are using commit `H` because of the name `master`, or because of the name `dev`.  Both branch names identify *the same commit* `H`.

Instead, make these configuration files *untracked* (and probably *ignored* as well).  That means Git never pays any attention to them.  They won't change when you switch from one commit to another, nor when you switch from one branch to another even if that means switching commits too.

Do the credential-and-database-based stuff in *different work-trees*.  Each Git repository comes with a work-tree, so you can just use two different clones of the same base repository to get two different work-trees easily.

If your Git is at least 2.5 (and preferably at least 2.15 because of a fairly big bug that was not fixed until then), you can use one Git repository with `git worktree add` to add a second work-tree to the one repository.

If you really insist on doing this all in one repository, and modifying files based on which branch *name* you gave to a recent `git checkout` or `git switch` command, consider using a post-checkout hook.  You can write any code you like in such a hook, and you can read the name of the branch that was used here.  Doing this is painful and full of pitfalls: the separate work-tree method is far superior, provided you can afford the disk space for it.