# Why is my Git ours merge strategy being ignored?

Tags: git, merge-strategy

I want to ignore a certain file from being overwritten regardless of whether there are changes. I have the following in `/etc/gitconfig`:

```
[merge "ours"]
        driver = true
```

And in the repository itself, in `.git/info/attributes`:

```
files/somefile.txt merge=ours
```

However, when I run `git pull`, the `somefile.txt` file is being overwritten regardless. Have I got this configured wrongly, or is there something I'm not understanding properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `merge=ours` only applies if a merge is actually needed, ie there have been changes to the file on both sides. It won't protect a file from any remote updates if it hasn't been modified locally. If this is the case, git simply checks out in a normal way. It never start doing a merge of the file, and so never even looks at the merge strategy.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22085876/1737957

Should you be using the ignore list instead to keep a local version of the file? This is what you should use if the file is different on every machine, or changes to it never need to be shared.

Comment: Basically I want a specific version of the file to be part of the repository so when people clone it they see the file, but then when a change is made (and committed) it can be ignored on a specific machine

Comment: OK I basically want to do what that answer says is impossible :P Thanks for the information

Comment: You probably want a slightly tweaked combination of local config files which never get checked in and general config files which have conditional sections or something equivalent...